# Typescript compiled javascript is not in corresponding file

Tags: typescript

I have this Typescript file defining Interfaces for the project. And when I'm looking in the compiled .js file for that exact file I don't see any compiled code. How come I can't see the equivalent code in this file?

Side note: in almost every other .js file in the build folder I can find the compiled ts code.

src/interfaces/company.ts

```
export interface Company {
  companyId: string;
  name: string;
  desc: string;
  presets: Preset[];
  locations: Location[];
  profileHistory: Profile[];
  subscriptions: Subscription[];
}

export interface CompanyInput {
  companyId: string;
  name: string;
  desc: string;
}
```

build/interfaces/company.js

```
"use strict";
//# sourceMappingURL=data:application/json;charset=utf-8;base64,eyJ2ZXJzaW9uIjozLCJzb3VyY2VzIjpbXSwibmFtZXMiOltdLCJtYXBwaW5ncyI6IiIsInNvdXJjZXNDb250ZW50IjpbXX0=
```

the base64 encoded string decodes to: `{"version":3,"sources":[],"names":[],"mappings":"","sourcesContent":[]}`

Comment: Interfaces don't exist in JavaScript, there's nothing concrete to output from that file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interfaces are there in TypeScript to enable a strong type check. Typescript restricts dynamic data binding and shows errors in compile-time, which saves from accidental type change in run time.  But on the other hand, Javascript has dynamically typed. So it does not require Interface. That's why you got nothing js file.